# Looping JavaScript Processes in Scrapy code

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

very new to Scrapy in particular and somewhat new to coding in general.

I'm trying to parse some data for my school project from this website: https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/sets/theme/ninjago

I want to parse data from a page, then move onto the next one and parse similar data from that one. However, since the "Next" page button is not a simple link but a Javascript command, I've set up the code to use a LUA script to simulate pressing the button to move to the next page and receive data from there, which looked something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

script = """
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    local c = args.counter

    for i=1,c do
        local button = splash:select_all('a.page-link')[12]
        button:click()
        assert(splash:wait(5))
    end

    return splash:html()
end
"""

class LegoTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'legotest'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/ninjago'
        
        yield SplashRequest(
            url=url, 
            callback=self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': script, 'url': url}
        )
    
    def parse(self, response):          
        products = response.css('div.mb-5')
        for product in products:
            yield {
                'name': product.css('h4 a::text').get(),
                'link': product.css('h4 a').attrib['href']
            }
```

However, although this worked, I wanted to be able to create a loop that went through all the pages and then returned data parsed from every single page.

I attempted to create something like this:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

lua_script = """
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))

    while not splash:select('div.mb-5') do
        splash:wait(0.1)
        print('waiting...')
    end
    return {html=splash:html()}
end
"""

script = """
function main(splash, args)
    assert(splash:go(args.url))
    local c = args.counter

    for i=1,c do
        local button = splash:select_all('a.page-link')[12]
        button:click()
        assert(splash:wait(5))
    end

    return splash:html()
end
"""

class LegoTestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'legotest'

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/ninjago'
        
        yield SplashRequest(
            url=url, 
            callback=self.parse,
            endpoint='execute',
            args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': lua_script, 'url': url}
        )
    
    def parse(self, response):          
        # Checks if it's the last page
        page_numbers = response.css('table.setstable td::text').getall()
        counter = -1
        while page_numbers[1] != page_numbers[2]:
            counter += 1
            yield SplashRequest(
                url='https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/ninjago',
                callback=self.parse_nextpage,
                endpoint='execute',
                args={'wait': 1, 'lua_source': script, 'url': 'https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/ninjago','counter': counter}
            )
            
    
    def parse_nextpage(self, response):
        products = response.css('div.mb-5')
        for product in products:
            yield {
                'name': product.css('h4 a::text').get(),
                'link': product.css('h4 a').attrib['href']
            }
```

However, when I run this code, it returns the first page of data, then gives a timeout error:

2024-02-18 17:26:18 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET https://www.brickeconomy.com/sets/theme/ninjago via http://localhost:8050/execute> (failed 1 times): 504 Gateway Time-out

I'm not sure why this happens, and would like to find a solution to fix it.